# Asynchronous Suspension while performing Head call in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, http-headers, dio

Below is the method for Head request call :

```
Future<Response> head(BuildContext context, String endUrl) async {
    mDio.options.baseUrl = apiBaseUrl;
    return await (_dio.head(endUrl)).catchError((e) {
      if (e.response.statusCode == 401) {
        //move to login page
      }
      /* else if (!checkSessionExpire(e, context)) {
        throw e;
      }*/
      else {
        throw e;
      }
    });
  }
```

Calling above method as below :

```
Future<Response?> headCallToGetModifiedDate(BuildContext context,String apiEndPoint) async{
    Response? response;
    Logger logger =Logger();
    try {
      response = await ApiService().head(context, apiEndPoint);
      logger.e("head call response >>  ${response.headers.value("").toString()}");
    }
    // ignore: avoid_catches_without_on_clauses
    on DioError catch(e)
    {
      response = (e.response);
      print("head call -------Exception----${e.toString()}");
    }
    return response;
  }
```

as you can see above at below line:

```
response = await ApiService().head(context, apiEndPoint);
```

The above method is calling from a Provider I have created as below:

```
Future<void> headCall(BuildContext context,String endUrl) async{
if(await checkNetworkConnection(context))
{
  var resErrMsg = "";
  Response? response = await AuthApiManager().headCallToGetModifiedDate(context, endUrl);
  try{
    logger.e("Head Call Response >>   $response");
    print(">>>>last modified >>>  "+response!.headers.value("Last-Modified").toString());
    if(response.statusCode == 200)
    {
      print("status code 200");
    }
    else {
      resErrMsg = response.statusMessage!.toString();
      logger.e("...head call..Response else..$response");
    }
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    logger.e("-----Error---headcall----" + e.toString());
  }
}
```

at this line:

```
Response? response = await AuthApiManager().headCallToGetModifiedDate(context, endUrl);
```

and finally in my Home screen I am calling above method using provider stuff,
but getting below error:

> I/flutter (30309): API call : headers {Authorization: Bearer }
> I/flutter (30309): API call : http://s3.ap-south-naws.com/file.json
> I/flutter (30309): API call : queryParameters {}
> I/flutter (30309): API call : null
> I/flutter (30309): medium true
> I/flutter (30309): API call : Http status error [400]
> I/flutter (30309): API call :
>
> I/flutter (30309): head call -------Exception----DioError
> [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400] I/flutter (30309):
> Source stack: I/flutter (30309): #0      DioMixin.fetch
> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488:35) I/flutter (30309): #1
> DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483:12) I/flutter
> (30309): #2      DioMixin.head (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:179:12)
> I/flutter (30309): #3      ApiService.head
> (package:mahotsav/src/apis/api_service.dart:211:24) I/flutter (30309):
> #4      AuthApiManager.headCallToGetModifiedDate (package:mahotsav/src/apis/apimanagers/auth/auth_api_manager.dart:39:37)
> I/flutter (30309): #5      HomeProvider.headCall
> (package:mahotsav/src/framework/dataProvider/Home/homeProvider.dart:1741:51)
>
> I/flutter (30309):  I/flutter (30309): #6
> _HomeScreenState.initState. (package:mahotsav/src/ui/home/home_screen.dart:68:9) I/flutter
> (30309):

What might going wrong here?

Comment: context may no longer be valid after the await.  You should check mounted to verify that the widget hasn't gone away.

Comment: can you please explain in detail?